# dojo form validation clearing

Tags: forms, validation, dojo, dijit.form

I am using dijit.form.ValidationTextBox for my form. The problem is I am repopulating the data using client side code and I am not doing a postback for a new form. The error message sticks around when I dynamically set the form data. 
I have tried calling reset but that had no effect so I assume its not what I want to do...

dijit.byId("MyForm").reset();

I just want to clear all of the validation messages when I populate my form with new data, even if that data is not valid. I don't want the messages to show up until I hit submit again..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to do the reset() on the individual form widget themselves.

registry.byId(textBoxId).reset();

And that should clear the input's error validation messages from the last submit.